# Collect same ids in Laravel Blade pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, laravel-blade

I have a pivot table with two foreign keys and I want to list items according to one foreign key.

```
    id | tool_id | user_id
    ______________________
    1    2         12
    2    5         12
    3    3         12
    4    4          7
```

I have relations between tables and I want to list tools by the user like this:

```
    No: User  Tools
    --- ----  -----
      1 John  2,3,5
      2 Sara  4
```

I loop the records but as you can guess it's listing as:

```
No: User  Tools
--- ----  -----
1   John  2
2   John  3
3   John  5
4   Sara  4

----or----


No: User  Tools
--- ----  -----
1   John  2,3,5
2   John  2,3,5
3   John  2,3,5
4   Sara  4
```

How can I list them as below?

```
 No: User  Tools
 --- ----  -----
   1 John  2,3,5
   2 Sara  4
```

This what tried so far:

`$assign` gets all data from pivot table and schema is in top of the post.

```
        <table class="table mb-0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Tool</th>
                <th scope="col">Employee</th>
                <th scope="col">Department</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($assigns as $assign)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$assign->employee->last_name." ".$assign->employee->first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$assign->employee->department->name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach($assigns->where('employee_id', $assign->employee_id) as $tool)
                            {{$tool->tool->tool_code}}
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function assignLetter(){
        $assigns = ToolAssign::all();
        $employees = Employee::where('status', 1)->where('is_inspector', 1)->orderBy('last_name')->get();
        return view('tool.assign', compact('assigns', 'employees'));
    }
```

**Pivot table's model**

```
public function employee()

    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, "employee_id", "id");
    }
    
    public function tool()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tool::class, "tool_id", "id");
    }
```

Comment: can u also share ur actual code trying to achieve it? so we can see what u tried so far

Comment: @ericmp thank you for reminding. I've added the code currently dealing with.

Comment: share the controller method which returns that view too (:

Comment: Please share your models with us to take a look.

Comment: are u loading the relations? `$myModels = Mymodel::with(['my_other_model'])->get();` - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @ericmp No need to relations. Just want to list the raw data. I didn't manage to list in my mind. If I can list, I think relations will be the easy part. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in hard way. It's not stupid if it works :)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Tool</th>
            <th scope="col">Employee</th>
            <th scope="col">Department</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @php($index = 1)
    @foreach($employees as $collect)
        @if(\App\Models\ToolAssign::where('employee_id', $collect->id)->count() > 0)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$index}}</th>
                <td>{{$collect->last_name." ".$collect->first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$collect->department->name}}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach(\App\Models\ToolAssign::where('employee_id', $collect->id)->get() as $codes)
                        @if($loop->last)
                            {{$codes->tool->tool_code}}
                        @else
                            {{$codes->tool->tool_code}},
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
            @php($index ++)
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your relationship type from `belongsTo` to `belongsToMany` like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class User extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the tools that the user belongs to.
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function tools(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tool::class);
    }
}
```

This way you could do something like this: (not tested)

```
foreach (User::all() as $user) {
    echo $user->id . ' - ' . $user->name . ' - ' . $user->tool->pluck('id')->join(', ');
}
```

EDIT:

Here is an example for your code to achieve what you want, but it's really messy. I suggest you to try my code above to fix it.

```
    <table class="table mb-0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Tool</th>
            <th scope="col">Employee</th>
            <th scope="col">Department</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($assigns as $assign)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$assign->employee->last_name." ".$assign->employee->first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$assign->employee->department->name}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ $assigns->where('employee_id', $assign->employee_id)->get()->map(function($tool) { return $tool->tool->tool_code; })->join(', '); }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: My question is not about relations. It should be really simple and I didn't manage to do that in a loop with raw data. We are focusing the wrong side of the question. :D

Comment: @VitoAndolini I see a problem with your relation that doesn't let you achieve the result you want. With this example you should've get what you expect. (The listing). Have you tried changing your relationship and trying something like I said?

Comment: Yes and I didn't manage to make it work. Tired up refactoring and post my stupid solution. :)

Comment: @VitoAndolini well, I edited my message and tried to simplify it. Hope it helps.